# Tweaking sfx exe file not to be opened by WinRAR or any other extraction utility

Tags: packages, portable, exec, self-extracting

Is it possible to change a .sfx.exe file to disguise its real identity and behave like a real PE?

Is there any other packager tool to make a standalone or autonomous exe that consists of, for example, a vbs file and its prerequisites, so that the user cannot manually extract the elements?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It makes your archive basically unusable on anything but the os+archictecture combination you're on.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably asking about
[Executable compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression).

SFX is not the right tool for it. You might have a look at these free tools :

- [UPX](https://upx.github.io/) (open source)
- [App packager (MakeAppx.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/make-appx-package--makeappx-exe-)
  by Microsoft, requires installing the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK),
  which might be too heavy for the job.

However, please note that every packaged file can be unpackaged by using
the right tools.